# RealmList does not accept null values

Tags: java, json, list, gson, realm

I'm using Gson and Retrofit2 as a REST Client stack, for usual list and object I don't have any problem during conversation, but when I have a property with type of RealmList in my classes and if json string of that property equals to null life became dark and I receive this error.

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RealmList does not
>   accept null values 01-02 15:04:46.261
>   17689-17689/com.hojan.mobile.footkal W/System.err:     at
>   io.realm.RealmList.checkValidObject(RealmList.java:772) 01-02
>   15:04:46.261 17689-17689/com.hojan.mobile.footkal W/System.err:     at
>   io.realm.RealmList.add(RealmList.java:194) 01-02 15:04:46.261
>   17689-17689/com.hojan.mobile.footkal W/System.err:     at
>   io.realm.RealmList.add(RealmList.java:52)

Is there any way to to set default value for RealmLists instead of null.

**example codes**

java class:

```
public class Post extends RealmObject {
    @SerializedName("PostId")
    @Expose
    @PrimaryKey
    private String postId;
    @SerializedName("Comments")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<Comment> comments = new RealmList<>();
}
```

json string:

```
{"PostId":"213c6c49-2d02-4754-b319-e6b635eca4bb","Comments":[null]}
```

Comment: The code that creates the RealmList, and the JSON format are somewhat relevant to this question

Comment: @EpicPandaForce post updated

Comment: It's because that's not a `null` property, it's a JSONArray with a `null` element in it. So it's a `1-length` list where the only value in it is `null`. This kind of "malformed" response would also break RxJava2, for example.

Comment: yes I'm using RxJava, so what can I do?!

Comment: You could add a type adapter that filters possible null values in the lists you receive.